# What's the difference between Bundler tools? (vite, rollup)

Tags: build, bundle, vite, rollup

I just make my own npm library, and I have to build this now.
So I find build tool, like vite, rollup, and so on...
And I wonder what is the best build tool of them.

I usually use vite(for website), cause it is simple for me, but the libraries I've found mostly use rollup (and webpack).

1. I find that vite use rollup to bundle. then, what is the difference of them? why library mostly use rollup than vite?
2. what are the best build tools to bundle into npm libraries?
3. what are the best build tools to bundle into website? (use React, Svelte...)
4. if 2,3 is different, why?

Answer (score 1):

Vite is primarily focused on providing a fast development experience for modern frameworks, leveraging native browser capabilities and hot module replacement.

Rollup, on the other hand, is a more general bundler, optimized for creating highly optimized production bundles, with a wide range of customization options and support for various module formats.